# How to plot the ROC Curve for a multilabel model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am not sure how to proceed with printing the ROC curve and I would much appreciate if I could get an explanation on how to plot it.

```
# Get prediction probability of the positive outcomes for each model

pred_bayes_prob = bayes_model.predict_proba(feature_test)

pred_dtc_prob = dtc_model.predict_proba(feature_test)

pred_knn_prob = knn_model.predict_proba(feature_test)

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
#ovr = one versus rest

bayes_auc = roc_auc_score(target_test, pred_bayes_prob, average = 'weighted', multi_class='ovr')
dtc_auc = roc_auc_score(target_test, pred_dtc_prob, average = 'weighted', multi_class='ovr')
knn_auc = roc_auc_score(target_test, pred_knn_prob, average = 'weighted', multi_class='ovr')

print('Naive Bayes: AUROC = %.3f' % (bayes_auc))
print('Decision Tree: AUROC = %.3f' % (dtc_auc))
print('K-Nearest Neighbour: AUROC = %.3f' % (knn_auc))

#calculate the ROC curve

bayes_fpr, bayes_tpr, bayes_thresholds = roc_curve(target_test, pred_bayes_prob, pos_label = bayes_model.classes_[1])
dtc_fpr, dtc_tpr, dtc_thresholds = roc_curve(target_test, pred_dtc_prob, pos_label = dtc_model.classes_[1])
knn_fpr, knn_tpr, knn_thresholds = roc_curve(target_test, pred_knn_prob, pos_label = knn_model.classes_[1])
```

When I am trying to run the roc_curve command to plot the curve I get an error. I am aware that the ROC curve is for binary classification problems and sklearn has added support for multilabel from version 0.21, however, I am not sure on how to implement it correctly. I tried many other questions but I could not solve this issue specifically, I would appreciate if you could give a hint on how to solve this.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2024/106121641.py in <module>
      1 #calculate the ROC curve
      2 #r_fpr, r_tpr = roc_curve
----> 3 bayes_fpr, bayes_tpr, bayes_thresholds = roc_curve(target_test, pred_bayes_prob, pos_label = bayes_model.classes_[1])
      4 dtc_fpr, dtc_tpr, dtc_thresholds = roc_curve(target_test, pred_dtc_prob, pos_label = dtc_model.classes_[1])
      5 knn_fpr, knn_tpr, knn_thresholds = roc_curve(target_test, pred_knn_prob, pos_label = knn_model.classes_[1])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight, drop_intermediate)
    960 
    961     """
--> 962     fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
    963         y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight
    964     )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in _binary_clf_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight)
    733     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)
    734     y_true = column_or_1d(y_true)
--> 735     y_score = column_or_1d(y_score)
    736     assert_all_finite(y_true)
    737     assert_all_finite(y_score)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
   1036         return np.ravel(y)
   1037 
-> 1038     raise ValueError(
   1039         "y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape)
   1040     )

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (65, 6) instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Yellowbrick’s](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/rocauc.html#multi-class-rocauc-curves) **ROCAUC Visualizer** does allow for plotting *multiclass classification curves*. **ROC curves** are typically used in binary classification, and in fact, the **Scikit-Learn** *roc_curve* metric is only able to perform metrics for *binary classifiers*. **Yellowbrick** addresses this by binarizing the output (per class) or using **one-vs-rest (micro score)** or **one-vs-all (macro score)** strategies of classification.

From the [Documentation](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/rocauc.html#multi-class-rocauc-curves):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, LabelEncoder

from yellowbrick.classifier import ROCAUC
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_game

# Load multi-class classification dataset
X, y = load_game()

# Encode the non-numeric columns
X = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(X)
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)

# Create the train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

# Instaniate the classification model and visualizer
model = RidgeClassifier()
visualizer = ROCAUC(model, classes=["win", "loss", "draw"])

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)        # Fit the training data to the visualizer
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)        # Evaluate the model on the test data
visualizer.show()                       # Finalize and render the figure
```

[image]